# USA (or worldwide) Equivalent of H2020-ITN program

Tags: funding, united-states, europe, research-proposal

I am involved in the preparation of a project proposal. If you are from Europe and you do research the chances are high that you have heard of the Horizon 2020 (H2020) programme. For the ones who are not from Europe or don't know,  *H2020 is the biggest EU Research and Innovation programme ever with nearly €80 billion of funding available over 7 years (2014 to 2020), more info [here](https://ec.europa.eu/programmes/horizon2020/en/what-horizon-2020).*

This programme, like many others,  is divided into different sections and specific calls. One of them is the Innovative Training Network (ITN) call.

**The Innovative Training Networks (ITN) aim to train a new generation of creative, entrepreneurial and innovative early-stage researchers, able to face current and future challenges and to convert knowledge and ideas into products and services for economic and social benefit.**

Basically, if the project proposal gets accepted you can have funding for several PhD students located at different universities or industries in Europe and you can do research on a common macro-topic (e.g., Automotive, Medical Robotics, Skin Cancer). There will be exchanges between research laboratories and workshops/trainings activities.

My question is: by reading the description above, do you know about any program like that in USA or anywhere else outside of Europe?

So far, I found only [this programme](https://www.onr.navy.mil/Science-Technology/Directorates/office-research-discovery-invention/Sponsored-Research/University-Research-Initiatives/MURI.aspx) (based in USA).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a variety of NSF multi-university project types that cover these kinds of things (including industry/national lab connections).

Comment: @Jon Custer, thanks a lot for your comment. Could you link some of them for me?

Comment: I've never applied for one, only been on the end of being asked by universities if my national lab would consider playing...

Answer (score 1):

The closest analogue for this mechanism in the US may be among those available through the NSF Division of Graduate Education (DGE) - [see active opportunities here](https://www.nsf.gov/funding/pgm_list.jsp?org=DGE). The training topics involved are often very macro-level.